# Encode PNG for delivery via JSON to Objective C/iOS device suddenly not working

Tags: objective-c, json, ruby-on-rails-4, base64, rabl

**SOLVED**

There was an exercise in futility.

24 hours to discover it was a comma in the wrong place.

```
@sysMessage.messagePictureData = Base64.strict_encode64(open(imagestring).read),
@sysMessage.messagePuzzleNumber = "#{sendPiece}"
```

Two things concatenated and hours lost. Thanks to those who read this.

**UPDATE**

I now seem to have the files being read and encoded "properly" ... in that I'm seeing what I'm expecting in terms of encoded data. But I have no idea why the JSON is coming down enclosing the data in square brackets and quotes (and adding another value!).

```
messagePictureData = "[\"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANgAAADYCAYAAACJIC3tAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAMSZJREFUeNrsnQmcFOWZ/9/qqr67p+e+mJPhmINBjhkYAQFFUMEo4JGN2Rz6j8lqotnsJqtxs6sxnzWa7Gpi1jMbNcb7wFsEuQTkZm ... [LOTS OF DATA] ... JZlUmyRSYkV+5NtGf5B2KdORE1ZLMK1kCCkD5oF1I8Pl+gu22gftAT7u4/1+AiwEhfhIPFXJaMLpvZFUlRMzsUNWIyMqs/QcwcTDKlBdsNrcHOwSZ13bQd2rn49yfASGdVDzofwWIHPsXy+PDylRK1g5FIBBiJRICRSKRPyME0+klIJHIwEmlM6P8LMACzov3UuDGSEwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\", \"30\"]";
```

How do I get Objective C to just read the first part in the brackets? I'm drawing a complete blank!

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'm sure there are better ways, but I have a Rails Server which **was** encoding PNG image files from AWS and, using RABL, encoding them into JSON (with a lot of other data) which was being delivered to my iOS device and being saved as a photo in Core Data.

It was all working, but now it's not and I am wondering if someone could take a look and see where it's going wrong. Sadly, I did a bundle update on my computer and this has updated a LOT of gems and Rails itself. Sigh. I consequently have no idea if there is a problem with one of the gems (and not a highly proficient debugger to try and sort it out) or my code.

**Rails Controller code:**

The code looks if there is a photo held on AWS. If there is, it looks for the URL, or provides a placeholder image URL if there isn't an image. I then need it to read the file and store it in a the database for delivery.

```
if (@photos.approvedMainPhoto == true)
  imagestring = eval "@photos.photoImage#{sendPiece}.url"
else
  imagestring = "#{::Rails.root}/public/images/placeholders/smallimageplaceholder.png"
end

@sysMessage = Message.new
...
@sysMessage.messagePictureData = File.open(imagestring, "r").read,
...
if (@sysMessage.save)
  [true, @sysMessage.id]
else
  [false, 0]
end
```

**RABL Code**

I've stripped some of the code out but I have coded that if there is picture data (and there isn't always going to be a photo), then encode it using Base64.strict_encode64 what is held in the database for transport.

```
object false
node(:message) { @code }
node(:number) { @nummessages }
child @messages, :object_root => false do   
    node(:messagePictureData, :if => lambda { |m| m.messageText == ""}) do |m|
            Base64.strict_encode64(m.messagePictureData)
    end
end
```

This seems to be delivering something. When I ask for the output in my XCode Console ... I get something similar to:

The JSON encoded data is saying:

```
messagePictureData = "WyJceDg5UE5HXHJcblx1MDAxQVxuXHUwMDAwXHUwMDAwXHUwMDAwXHJJSERSXHUwMDAwXHUwMDAwXHUwMDAwXHhEOFx1MDAwMFx1MDAwMFx1MDAwMFx4RDhcYlx1MDAwNlx1MDAwMFx1MDAwMFx1MDAwMFx4ODkgLVx4RURcdTAwMDBcdTAwMDBcdTAwMDBcdTAwMTl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmVcdTAwMDBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5cVx4QzllPFx1MDAwMFx1MDAwMDEmSURBVHhceERBXHhFQ1x4OURcdFx4OUNcdTAwMTRceEU1XHg5OVx4RkZceERG6qq .... [LOTS MORE] ... HhDMWJcYT5ceEM1XHhGMlx4RjhceEYwXHhGMlx4OTVcdTAwMTJceEI1XHg4M1x4OTFIXHUwMDA0XHUwMDE4XHg4OURceDgwXHg5MUhceEE0T1x4QzhceEMxNFx4RkFJSCRyMFx1MDAxMmlMXHhFOFx4RkZcdjBcdTAwMDBceEIzXHhBMlx4RkTUuDFceDkyXHUwMDEzXHUwMDAwXHUwMDAwXHUwMDAwXHUwMDAwSUVORFx4QUVCYFx4ODIiLCAiMzAiXQ==";
```

When I put it through the following code in Objective C:

**Objective C Code:**

```
NSLog(@"I have the message Picture Data as: %@", message[@"messagePictureData");

NSData *photo = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:message[@"messagePictureData"] options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

NSLog(@"I have the photo data as: %@", photo);
```

I get the following output in the Console:

```
I have the photo data as: <5b225c78 3839504e 475c725c 6e5c7530 3031415c 6e5c7530 3030305c 75303030 305c7530 3030305c 72494844 ... [LOTS MORE] ... 3839445c 7838305c 78393148 5c784134 4f5c7843 385c7843 31345c78 46414948 2472305c 75303031 32694c5c 7845385c 7846465c 76305c75 30303030 5c784233 5c784132 5c784644 d4b8315c 7839325c 75303031 335c7530 3030305c 75303030 305c7530 3030305c 75303030 3049454e 445c7841 4542605c 78383222 2c202233 30225d>
```

It say's that it's saving the image in Core Data. However, what I'm getting are transparent squares and not photos.

And, every so often, when it's trying to get a slice from AWS, I get the following log error ... which also means nothing to me!

WARN: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://XXXXXXXXXX.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/photo/photoImage20/77/photoImage20.jpg ... [lots more]

When I place the complete URL pointing to Amazon into Safari, it shows the photo perfectly. Sigh.

Any help would be gratefully received as, once again, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

There was an exercise in futility.

24 hours to discover it was a comma in the wrong place.

```
@sysMessage.messagePictureData = Base64.strict_encode64(open(imagestring).read),
@sysMessage.messagePuzzleNumber = "#{sendPiece}"
```

Two things concatenated and hours lost.

Thanks to those who read this.